# Replace the header of a given column with the filename

Tags: text-processing, awk, filenames

I have many vcf files

```
HR001.vcf
HR002.vcf
HR003.vcf
HR004.vcf
HR005.vcf
HR006.vcf
HR007.vcf
HR008.vcf
.
.
```

In the **10th column** of EACH file the colum header is $i. In each file, I would like to replace $i with the basename of the files.
For example for file HR001.vcf, $i=HR001, for HR002.vcf $i=HR002 etc...
is there a simple way to do this in unix. I own a macbook pro but I am new to this.
These are actually VCF files with tab-delimited field. Yes each file has 236 row that should be skipped. I am interested in the row that start with #CHROM, which is row # 237 and the column #10 of that row 237 contains $i

Comment: What are those VCF files? Is that vcard files or [variant call format files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_Call_Format)? Is it *text* based? What's the format of the header? How are "columns" delimited? Can you provide a sample?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an example and the output you expect from that example. If these are actually VCF files, the fields are tab-separated and that is an essential piece of information. They also have headers, which presumably should be skipped. It sounds like you want to add the sample name to the VCF file, but if so, that should _only_ be done on one specific header line (the one that starts with `#CHROM`) and not on every line. So please add an example so we can understand what you mean.

Comment: Yes Terdon, you hit it on the nail.  These are actually VCF files with tab-delimited field. Yes each file has 236 row that should be skipped. I am interested in the row that start with #CHROM, which is row # 237 and the column #10 which contains $i

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `perl`:

```
perl -F'\t' -i -lape '
  if ($F[0] eq "#CHROM" && $F[9] eq q($i)) {
    $F[9] = ($ARGV =~ s/\.vcf$//r);
    $_ = join "\t", @F
  }' -- *.vcf
```

Answer (score 0):

Script like this can do the work:

```
cd /path/to/direcrtory
for i in *.vcf
do
awk '{if (FNR==1) $10=FILENAME; print}' "$i" >"$i.tmp" && mv -f "$i.tmp" "$i"
done
```

The "magic" is in variable `FILENAME` which in `awk` contain the input filename

Comment: But `FILENAME` will contain `/path/to/direcrtory/HR001.vcf`, not `HR001`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, correct. And the samples way is to be in this directory. WIll correct my script :)

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your files are spaces delimited this should work:

```
for f_name in HR[0-9]*.vcf; do
    awk -v f="${f_name%.*}" 'NR == 1 {$10 = f}1' "$f_name" > "$f_name.tmp"
    mv "$f_name.tmp" "$f_name"
done
```

Loop inside the directory and grab each `vcf` file. Then remove the extension from the filename with `${f_name%.*}` and pass it as a parameter to `awk`.

`awk` will use this as the filename to do the sobstitution. **NOTE** : this need to run inside the same directory of the `vcf` file, if you want to run it from another path use the following:

```
for f_name in /some/full/path/HR[0-9]*.vcf; do
    # remove the path
    f="${f_name##*/}"
    awk -v f="${f%.*}" 'NR == 1 {$10 = f}1' "$f_name" > "$f_name.tmp"
    mv "$f_name.tmp" "$f_name"
done
```

If the files are not spaces delimited fix `awk FS`.

**EDIT FOR NEW REQUESTS AND BASED ON @Ed Morton IMPROVEMENTS**

> I am interested in the row that start with #CHROM, which is row # 237 and the column #10 of that row 237 contains $i

```
for f_name in /some/full/path/HR[0-9]*.vcf; do
    # remove the path
    f="${f_name##*/}"
    awk -F'\t' -v f="${f%.*}" 'NR == 237 {$10 = f}1' "$f_name" > "$f_name.tmp" && mv "$f_name.tmp" "$f_name"
done
```

This new version of the scripts do the replacement with the file name only in the field you like `($10 = f)` and in the line that you want `(NR == 237)`. The `awk` parameter `-F\t` set how `awk` see rows and split those in fields.

Again thanks to @Ed Morton which have improved the original scripts:
As you can see the statement : `mv "$f_name.tmp" "$f_name"` which is the command the overwrite the old file with the content of the new (produced by `awk`) is condensed in one line: `awk '' file > tmp && mv tmp file` in this way if the `awk` command fails the right part of the `&&`  is not executed and the original data will kept safe

Comment: Never do `cmd file > tmp; mv tmp file`, always do `cmd file > tmp && mv tmp file` instead so you don't zap the input file if the command fails.

Comment: @EdMorton Great! If use the `END` statement to write the whole file dose it work the same way as you point out?

Comment: You mean something like storing the eventual output in an awk array and overwriting the original input file using a loop in the END section so everythings done inside awk instead of writing to a tmp file? In general I'd avoid doing that as you can run out of memory for huge input files and it's always best to let awk do what it does best (manipulate text) and shell do what it does best (create/destroy files and processes and sequence calls to tools). If you meant something else, I'm not sure what, sorry.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser, thanks you. The row #237 of the file has tab-separated field. I think awk FS will work, but I an not sure how to use it/where to put it. thanks

Comment: @YetAnotherUser, based on your suggestion, here is the command that I am finally using. however. the $i is not replace by HR001, I get both $i   HR001 in the same header of column 10. 
for f_name in HR[0-9]*.vcf; do
awk -v FS="${f_name%.*}" 'NR==237 {$10=FS}1' "$f_name" > "$f_name.tmp"
mv "f_name.tmp" "$f_name"
done

Comment: @EdMorton Yes i mean exactly that. But you're right, your approach is best, i will edit my answers

Comment: OK, you'd have a very similar issue because if your script failed for some reason during writing in the END section you'd have trashed your input file. Writing to a temp file and them moving it onto the original is the safest way to go (and is what all "inline" editing tools do in the background except for `ed` which uses a buffer).

Comment: @dounix in your first request, before the edit, you have not specified the other requirements, i will edit my answers

Comment: @dounix check now

Comment: @EdMorton Again thanks! I have edited based on you improvements

Comment: @YetAnotherUser. Thanks you!, Yes the new "EDIT FOR NEW REQUESTS AND BASED ON Ed Morton IMPROVEMENTS" script does a good job of replacing the $i in column 10 with the basename of the sample in row 237. The only issue now is that row 237, which is the header is not tab-delimited to match the column. how can that be fixed? THANY YOU!!

Comment: @dounix im happy about that, but as you can see from the first line of my answer: `Supposing your files are spaces delimited this should work`. If the file is not `space`, or `tab` delitmited you should post a sample of the file to let us understand  and help you

Answer (score 0):

[image]@YetAnotherUser,
please see an image of the sample file regarding my request: "Replace the header of a given column with the filename"

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please don't post edit as answers but edit the answer itself.

Comment: And the sample data should not be posted as image

Comment: @YetAnotherUser, thank you and well noted. I am learning, it is my first. sorry! thank you very much for your help

Comment: @YetAnotherUser, I tried the revised script but row 237 is not tab delimited. It is a single line with word separated by space

Comment: sorry i can't understand what you say. If you don't post a sample of the file as a text i can't help you.

Comment: @dounix Please don't add additional information about your problem in answers or comments where we have to go looking for it and can easily miss it. Simply edit your question to contain all relevant information about the problem you're asking for help with.